# Android In app billing with subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've been following the tutorial on Google on how to set up in app purchases using the sample code from TrivialDrive.
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample

I've create a few in app products, but I can only query the "managed products' and not the 'subcriptions'

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
 final IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
            mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                toast("query fail");
                return;
            }

            SkuDetails subscription =  inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_SUBSCRIPTION);
            SkuDetails test =  inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_TEST);
            if(subscription != null) {
                toast("subscription: " + subscription.toString());
                // update the UI
            }
            else {
                toast("subscription: null " + inventory.toString());
            }
        }
    };
```

SkuDetails subcription is always null, but SkuDetails test is not, I've create multiple subscriptions and managed products, but its only the subscriptions that don't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Prepare sku list bundle

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
skuList.add(SKU_TEST);
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList(“ITEM_ID_LIST”, skuList);
```

and call the getSkuDetails method on the In-app Billing Version 3 API, passing the method the In-app Billing API version (“3”), the package name of your calling app, the purchase type (“subs”), and the Bundle that you created.

```
Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
   getPackageName(), "subs", querySkus);
```

Comment: Yeah, I eventually realized after that "subs" is for subscriptions. Google doesn't mention this is their tutorial which is really weird...

Comment: @random I am trying to add the monthly and yearly subscriptions for my app. I have some clarifications, can you able to add any input on this and what are the additional things I need to handle if the support is from the UI alone.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927954/clarificaion-does-the-billing-subscription-and-handle-the-subscription-state-in